# Please explain this early termination of multiprocess.Process subclass?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have the following test code subclassing Process from [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class TestProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('{} says "I am alive"'.format(self.name))

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    procs = [TestProcess(i) for i in list('ABC')]

    try:
        for p in procs:
            print('starting {}'.format(p.name))
            p.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('caught interrupt')
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        for p in procs:
            print('stopping {}'.format(p.name))
            p.terminate()
```

for some reason A terminates early without ever sending <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and process B and C never seem to run:

```
host:~ user$ python process_example.py
    starting A
    starting B
    starting C
    A says "I am alive"
    [... x 16 lines]
    A says "I am alistopping A
    stopping B
    stopping C
```

If anyone can explain this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Update**

Thanks all for the prompt responses; I've updated to the following:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

class TestProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('{} says "I am alive"'.format(self.name))
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    procs = [TestProcess(i) for i in list('ABC')]

    try:
        for p in procs :
            print('starting {}'.format(p.name))
            p.start()
        for p in procs :
            print('joining {}'.format(p.name))
            p.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('caught interrupt')
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        for p in procs :
            print('stopping {}'.format(p.name))
            p.terminate()
```

Now I get:

```
host:~ user$ python process_example.py
starting A
starting B
starting C
A says "I am alive"
joining A
B says "I am alive"
C says "I am alive"
A says "I am alive"
B says "I am alive"
C says "I am alive"
A says "I am alive"
B says "I am alive"
C says "I am alive"
A says "I am alive"
B says "I am alive"
C says "I am alive"
A says "I am alive"
B says "I am alive"
C says "I am alive"
B says "I am alive"
A says "I am alive"
C says "I am alive"
^Ccaught interrupt
stopping A
stopping B
stopping C
```

So only joining one thread is necessary?

Comment: Why is this at all surprising? You don't wait for any of your processes to do anything, and nothing about this output suggests that A's termination is early.

Comment: Perhaps you've missed the point of running processes or threads. They run parallel to the main thread/process, so your code continues to move forward. Use `.join()` if you want to wait for the process to finish (in this case never).

Comment: Are you trying to *wait* for a Ctrl-C?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I'd like to run all processes until some event or interupt

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear to me what you expect this to do.  After starting the processes, the code immediately enters the `finally:` block and explicitly terminates all of them.  So of course they stop.

As to why only "A" says it's alive, that may vary across platforms (OS).  Your `run()` method is just a "busy loop", printing as fast as possible non-stop.  The processes are killed so soon after starting them that it looks like, on *your* platform, the OS never got around to scheduling a time slice for the other processes before you terminated them.

Try, e.g., sticking a `time.sleep(10)` after the loop that starts the processes.  That will delay killing the processes for 10 seconds, and that's probably enough time for `B` and `C` to get some love ;-) from the operating system before they're killed.